# Using regex in Python script

Tags: python, regex, search, replace

Am trying to write a python script to search and replace this line:

## time   residue 3   Total

with an empty line.

This is my script:

```
import glob


read_files = glob.glob("*.agr")

with open("out.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "r") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())

with open("out.txt", "r") as file:
    filedata = file.read()
filedata = filedata.replace(r'#time\s+residue\s+[0-9]\s+Total', 'x')
with open("out.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(filedata)
```

Using this, am not able to get any replacement. Why could that be? The rest of the code is working fine. The output file has not change to it so i suspect that the pattern cant be found.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The `str.replace` method replaces a fixed substring. Use `re.sub` instead if you're looking to replace a match of a regex pattern:

```
import re
filedata = re.sub(r'#time\s+residue\s+[0-9]\s+Total', 'x', filedata)
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked!